# Please bring back shading to accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer

The shading for accepted answers was a nice UI touch, please bring it back.

Comment: People will still notice if the `status-bydesign` tag is there. I'm Ron Burgundy?

Comment: By anyone I mean that the powers-that-be won't see it on their feature-request search that they do, since they exclude looking at the status-bydesign (and status-declined) tags. (As best as I remember, can't find the explanatory link right now.)

Comment: OK, they don't look at status-declined or status-deferred, but apparently still look at status-bydesign.  Good News.

Comment: Everyone will have to keep upvoting this question then ;)

Comment: For those reading the comments, Jeff has now changed this from status-bydesign to status-declined.  __All hope is gone.__

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's been turned off on the whole "Trilogy". See just above the last graphic [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/help-stackexchange-with-colors/comment-page-1/#comment-35677).

@Jeff: **Turn it back on,** ***please*!**

Comment: The SE sites open right now are chroma awful.

Comment: They look like a Mardi Gras parade crashed into an Easter-egg dye factory.

Comment: A Mardi Gras parade at least has a sense of colour.

Answer (score 23):

I see some people hated the *high* (for small ammount of high) contrast of the accepted answers' background, and some of us miss it.

Coul we have it back in at least a pale green colour?

Something like `#d3ffde`? This would be subtle enough and work the same way it used to for those of us that have already trained ourselfs at *not* looking to the checkmark :P

Answer (score 5):

Jeff changed it as one of the tweaks to the look & feel of the sites. From the lastest blog post [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/help-stackexchange-with-colors/)

> I just deployed a change to remove the accepted answer color to make color schemes a bit easier for SE. But I do believe that we can and should do much, much better than the existing Stack Exchange color schemes. Seriously, what does this say to you?

I am assuming this change was also applied to the rest of the Trilogy sites. It's a bit disconcerting but I do like it better. It does make answers easier to read, and helps on sites like SF or SU where we use screenshots on white backgrounds.

Comment: Good point about screenshots, that's why I kinda like the change too. E.g. this answer looks much better now: http://superuser.com/questions/32885/what-do-you-have-for-a-home-server-for-multimedia/32940#32940

Comment: I don't get the advantage of "screenshots on white backgrounds". The white background of a screenshot still shows white if the answer has a green background. If you want transparency, use a transparent image.

Answer (score 4):

The background colour doesn't contribute any additional information that the checkmark doesn't already. And, with users' own answers already being a different colour, it's confusing to remember which is which.

I don't mind the missing background, it looks cleaner.

Comment: +1, couldn't agree more.  In fact, the background was so dark as to make the text more difficult to read.

Comment: While it does look better, some sort of shading to help it stand out would be nice... just not something so... bold?

Comment: At first, I felt I miss the shading but now that I'm used to the new style, IMO it's much better .

Comment: -1, totally disagree. If there was a tiny bit of text buried under the answer saying "Accepted answer", then the checkmark "doesn't contribute any additional information". But you will surely agree that would be a bad design idea. The point of the green background is to convey the information **quickly**. Now I'm wondering on EVERY question if there is an accepted answer or not and consciously checking, rather than just knowing without thinking.